# "ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax;" in hibernate one to many relationship mapping

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I am trying to implement order management system by hibernate, which I am not very familiar with. The exception asked me to manually execute sql the same as hibernate in my program tried, and it succeeded. I don't know what's the problem. Probably it's from design issues. Database is like this:[image]

ORDER has a foreign key ITEM_ID pointing to ITEM_ID in ITEM table, it's a one to many relationship and another foreign key CLIENT_ID pointing to CLIENT_ID in CLINET table.
Three entities' definition with annotation are written as

```
@Table(name = "ITEM")
public class Item implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ITEM_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int item_id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="CATEGORY")
    private String category;
    @Column(name="UNIT")
    private String unit;
    @Column(name="PRICE")
    private double price;
    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CLIENT")
public class Client implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CLIENT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int client_id;
    @Column(name="CLIENT_NAME")
    private String client_name;
//getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="ORDER")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int order_id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,targetEntity=Client.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLIENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Client client;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,targetEntity=Item.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID", nullable = false)
    private Item item;
    @Column(name="QUANTITY")
    private double quantity;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "ORDER_DATE")
    private Date order_date;
//getters and setters
    }
```

The order data insertion function is like:

```
public static void insertNewOrder(Item item,Client client, double quantity, Date date){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setItem(item);
        order.setClient(client);
        order.setQuantity(new Double(quantity));
        order.setOrder_date(date);
        session.save(order);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

Here is my exception:

```
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER (CLIENT_ID, ITEM_ID, ORDER_DATE, QUANTITY) values (1, 1, '2013-11-12', 1.4' at line 1
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER (CLIENT_ID, ITEM_ID, ORDER_DATE, QUANTITY) values (1, 1, '2013-11-12', 1.4' at line 1
```

I have tried that sql manually, and it did insert successfully. I can't find any clue where the problem could be. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ORDER` is a MySQL keyword. If you must use it as a table name you need to wrap every reference in backticks.

```
SELECT * FROM `ORDER`...
```

I recommend you chnage the table name to something that doesn't conflict